# Rare occurrence: Instance fields not initialized on onResume in an Android activity

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, onresume

I have some instance fields in an Android activity that I initialize on `onCreate`, and then just use everywhere else within the activity.

But, sometimes (very rarely, once every few thousand uses) this instance field is `null` on `onResume`, leading to an immediate `NullPointerException`.

Here's a very simple working example:

```
class Foo {
}

class CrashingActivity extends Activity {
    private Foo foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        foo = new Foo();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.i("CrashingActivity", "Foo: " + foo); // CRASH!
    }
}
```

I don't think we need to use `onPause` or `onSaveInstanceState`, right?

Why is this crash happening?